# Fetch unique id of device using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, uniqueidentifier

I have a website which will be accessed only on chrome browser. I want to fetch the devices's(mostly android tab) unique id. This value has to be similar to imei no. I want to obtain this value using javascript. Is there a way to obtain device's unique id using javascript.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for the link. But I am trying to obtain the unique id for a website. But the link refers to android app development.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I misread the question. Then it's not possible *and most likely illegal*

Answer (score -1):

You can access device's uuid for this purpose

You can use [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) or [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/)

In Phonegap, you can use [Cordova Device Plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.device)

```
  /* Android: Returns a random 64-bit integer (as a string, again!)
      The integer is generated on the device's first boot

   BlackBerry: Returns the PIN number of the device
         This is a nine-digit unique integer (as a string, though!)

   iPhone: (Paraphrased from the UIDevice Class documentation)
     Returns a string of hash values created from multiple hardware identifies.
     It is guaranteed to be unique for every device and can't be tied
     to the user account.
   Windows Phone 7 : Returns a hash of device+current user,
        if the user is not defined, a guid is generated and will persist until the app is uninstalled
   Tizen: returns the device IMEI (International Mobile Equipment Identity or IMEI is a number
    unique to every GSM and UMTS mobile phone. */

  var deviceID = device.uuid;
```

In MoSync, you can use [<s>Javascript API</s>](http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/device.uuid.md.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Device Properties Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/wormhole.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Wormhole to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Wormhole is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');

    element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' + 
                        'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am trying to obtain the unique id for a website. If inclusion of wormhole.js works for html5 website, then can you tell me from where can I obtain the wormhole.js script.

Comment: it's not getting data. I tried

Comment: for wormhole, try https://gist.github.com/paoloboschini/5085780